# Why does Go map vs slice performance have 10x speed difference here

Tags: go

I just solved problem 23 on Project Euler, but I noticed a big difference between map[int]bool, and []bool in terms of performance.

I have a function that sums up the proper divisors of a number:

```
func divisorsSum(n int) int {
    sum := 1
    for i := 2; i*i <= n; i++ {
        if n%i == 0 {
            sum += i
            if n/i != i {
                sum += n / i
            }
        }
    }
    return sum
}
```

And then in main I do like this:

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    defer func() {
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", elapsed)
    }()

    n := 28123
    abundant := []int{}
    for i := 12; i <= n; i++ {
        if divisorsSum(i) > i {
            abundant = append(abundant, i)
        }
    }

    sums := map[int]bool{}
    for i := 0; i < len(abundant); i++ {
        for j := i; j < len(abundant); j++ {
            if abundant[i]+abundant[j] > n {
                break
            }
            sums[abundant[i]+abundant[j]] = true
        }
    }

    sum := 0
    for i := 1; i <= 28123; i++ {
        if _, ok := sums[i]; !ok {
            sum += i
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

This code takes 450ms on my computer. But if I change the main code to below with slice of bool instead of map like this:

```
func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    defer func() {
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", elapsed)
    }()

    n := 28123
    abundant := []int{}
    for i := 12; i <= n; i++ {
        if divisorsSum(i) > i {
            abundant = append(abundant, i)
        }
    }
    sums := make([]bool, n)
    for i := 0; i < len(abundant); i++ {
        for j := i; j < len(abundant); j++ {
            if abundant[i]+abundant[j] < n {
                sums[abundant[i]+abundant[j]] = true
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(sums); i++ {
        if !sums[i] {
            sum += i
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

Now it takes only 40ms, below 1/10 of the speed from previous. I thought maps were supposed to have faster look ups. What is up with the performance difference here?

Comment: Hi, I think this isn't fair comparison because when you use map for look up, then should expecting your key is any value and not incremental. Every time `map` look up for a key, it needs to search for its content. Your slices sample isn't random but a known index. In short, your map do `search` and `read`, your slice do `index` and `read`. `index` a slice faster than map key `search`. If the content mostly false and bigger `n`  then better map should be more memory efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can profile your code and see, but in general, there are two main reasons:

1. You pre-allocate `sums` in the second example to its desired size. This means it never has to grow, and all this is very efficient, there's no GC pressure, no reallocs, etc. Try creating the map with the desired size in advance and see how much it improves things.
2. I don't know the internal implementation of Go's hash map, but in general, random access of an array/slice by integer index is super efficient, and a hash table adds overhead on top of it, especially if it hashes the integers (it might do so to create better distribution).

Comment: I tried sums := make(map[int]bool, n) where n = 28123, but still above 450ms.

Comment: @Alex: there's an overhead to looking up values in a map, whereas as slice is directly indexing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Both slices and maps store the data in an underlying array.

In case of a **slice**, the index is known so the data can be looked up directly.

In case of a **map**, a hashing function is used to convert the key to an index, look up the entry by that index, verify the entry contains the desired key, and only then return the value stored in the entry.

The key verification in case of the map is required as the hashing function may generate the same output for multiple keys. There are various techniques to get around this issue. Additionally, Go doesn't grow maps immediately when it exceeds a certain load factor, rather it spreads the work across multiple writes. This also has to be taken into account when doing entry lookups, as it complicates the underlying data structure. All this house-keeping overhead costs time.